# Angular Animation - find the currently animating elements matched by :leave

Tags: angular, animation

I'm using `BrowserAnimationsModule`, and have some animations setup with the router so that the current component slides out, and the new/next component slides in when the user navigates. This works fine.

But, I now want to perform some actions at the start + end of each animation. I'm using the `AnimationEvent` [callback](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#animation-callbacks) to take action, but I need to know specifically which animating components (or just dom elements) are currently entering or leaving the dom, aka which ones are matched by `query(':enter')` or `query(':leave')`, so that I can, for example, target the specific component running the `:leave` animation. My animation looks like:

```
export function fadeIn() {
    return [
        query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' }), { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', style({ opacity: '0' }), { optional: true }),
        query(':leave', style({ opacity: '0' }), { optional: true }),
        group([
            query(':enter', group([
                animate('11000ms ease', style({opacity: '1'})),
                animateChild()
            ]), opt)
        ])
    ];
}
```

I know angular sets the class `ng-animating` while the anim is running, like so:
[image]
...but that's not enough to differentiate between a `:leave` and an `:enter`.

*In case you're wondering what I want to do - I want to set `pointer-events: none` on the `:leave` components/elements, to prevent users from clicking on the dom elements during this animation, because at the start of the animation, angular calls onDestroy() on the `:leave` component, which kinda breaks them, and so clicking on their dom elements during this time span where the animation is running can cause bugs. I'd prefer not to stuff code in each and every component's onDestroy() method to identify them as a ':leave' component, if there's a less tedious way.

I'm on angular 7, but open to solutions that may require upgrading.

**edit** - Adding clarification:
I was already using the AnimationEvent callback I mentioned above, but I cannot figure out how to tell which component or dom elements are entering or leaving. There's always 2 components animating at the same time, one entering, and one leaving. Look at the img I posted where there's `<app-splash>` and `<app-account-recovery>` both in the dom, both are children of the `class=router-outlet-wrapper` (router-outlet-wrapper is what `animEvent.element` always points to in both enter and leave event callbacks).

My code is very closely modeled after this ng example:

https://github.com/matsko/ng4-animations-preview/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html
https://github.com/matsko/ng4-animations-preview/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

Notice there's no animation code in each component ts file - it's all done in `AppComponent`, and so all components get placed as a sibling of `<router-outlet>`, and `AnimationEvent.triggerName` is always = `routerAnimations`

I did notice it seems like the :leave element is always the 2nd sibling after `<router-outlet>` - in my img, this means `<app-account-recovery>` is leaving, but it feels hacky to rely on such an unspecified detail.

**An acceptable answer must be able to tell me specifically which element is currently running the :leave animation.**

Comment: I checked that when destroyed component is animating there is no event listener on e.g. <button (click)=...>. And I guess same happens for all angular listeners - as soon as you dont add vanilla js listeners you should be fine -- no?

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: Maybe you could go with setting to the `html` pointer events none for the time of navigation?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov that's the problem - that ng removes its event listeners before :leave starts. In my case, I have a form element, who normally has submit event listeners that prevent it from submitting to the action attribute. But, these event handlers are gone, so if you click during that time, the form submits and causes much mayhem. I imagine other such bugs exist elsewhere in the app, and so I want to try to prevent user interaction entirely on :leave elements.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov disabling all pointer-events during anim might be an acceptable middle ground, although I prefer to let the :enter elements be interactable if possible, otherwise fast clicking users will get confused when their clicks "do nothing sometimes".

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is set `pointer-events` to `none` during animation for `:leave`, try setting it within the `query` itself:

```
query(':leave', style({ opacity: '0', 'pointer-events': 'none' }), { optional: true }),
```

Comment: I tried that before asking the question, and unless I made a mistake, it didn't work. I did work to add other styles, like a bg color, so I think I did it right, and even tried `pointerEvents` vs `pointer-events`.

Comment: @goat have you tried the `keyframes`? I think it might be that the pointer-events is assigned in the end. Instead, if you used keyframes with offset 0 it should help, as it would become the initial point rather than the last one

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AnimationEvent` to achieve that.

```
@Component({
  host: {
    '[@myAnimationTrigger]': 'someExpression',
    '(@myAnimationTrigger.start)': 'captureStartEvent($event)',
    '(@myAnimationTrigger.done)': 'captureDoneEvent($event)',
  },
  animations: [
    trigger("myAnimationTrigger", [
       // ...
    ])
  ]
})
class MyComponent {
  someExpression: any = false;
  captureStartEvent(event: AnimationEvent) {
    // the toState, fromState and totalTime data is accessible from the event variable
  }

  captureDoneEvent(event: AnimationEvent) {
    // the toState, fromState and totalTime data is accessible from the event variable
  }
}
```

The model is like:

```
interface AnimationEvent {
  fromState: string
  toState: string
  totalTime: number
  phaseName: string
  element: any
  triggerName: string
  disabled: boolean
}
```

You can determine if you are in `:leave` from these properties.

Comment: I had already tried this, but the `event.element` always points to my `class=router-outlet-wrapper` element. Please see my updated post - I edited the part below **edit**

Comment: @goat I think now you can make it very simple. Get all children elements. And if there are 3, then you need the 2nd and the 3rd

Comment: @Sergey but how do I know which of the two is leaving? Like I said in my post, counting on order is unspecified behavior and likely unreliable.

Comment: Filter array on their toState @Sergey

Comment: I have a feeling that the new route is always the last one

Comment: @Sergey my post mentions that.